# why my app automatic disconnect with expo CLI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

i am using react native expo but I am facing issue in starting the app , when the app start and the expo stopped working after it builds complete and I have to again restart the complete package and then it work again only for 1 minutes or less time , also I have upgraded my node JS chrome 8. to 10 I think the issue is from Node.js side

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and re-installing expo. Something similar was happening to me and it fixed the issue.

Comment: how can i delete expo CLI